# javascript - Unexpected behavior with hands on table JS library

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

I am facing a peculiar issue while using handsontable JS library, I am creating two instances of the table on a page the tables get rendered on the UI. However, I see that if I try to add a row in one of the tables it gets added to the other instance as well. Same is the case with the data, it gets copied between the instances. Can someone please help me out in figuring out the problem here.

```js
var dataObject = [
    {id: 1, flag: 'EUR', currencyCode: 'EUR', currency: 'Euro', level: 0.9033, units: 'EUR / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.0026},
    {id: 2, flag: 'JPY', currencyCode: 'JPY', currency: 'Japanese Yen', level: 124.3870, units: 'JPY / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.0001},
    {id: 3, flag: 'GBP', currencyCode: 'GBP', currency: 'Pound Sterling', level: 0.6396, units: 'GBP / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.00}
  ];
  var currencyCodes = ['EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'CAD', 'AUD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'BRL', 'CNY', 'RUB', 'INR', 'TRY', 'THB', 'IDR', 'MYR', 'MXN', 'ARS', 'DKK', 'ILS', 'PHP'];

  var flagRenderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    var currencyCode = value;

    while (td.firstChild) {
      td.removeChild(td.firstChild);
    }

    if (currencyCodes.indexOf(currencyCode) > -1) {
      var flagElement = document.createElement('DIV');
      flagElement.className = 'flag ' + currencyCode.toLowerCase();
      td.appendChild(flagElement);

    } else {
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(value === null ? '' : value);
      td.appendChild(textNode);
    }
  };

  var hotElement1 = document.querySelector('#hot1');
  var hotElement2 = document.querySelector('#hot2');
  var hotElementContainer1 = hotElement1.parentNode;
  var hotElementContainer2 = hotElement2.parentNode;
  var hotSettings = {
    data: dataObject,
    contextMenu:  ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row', 'make_read_only'],
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'id',
            type: 'numeric',
            width: 40
        },
        {
            data: 'flag',
   renderer: flagRenderer
        },
        {
            data: 'currencyCode',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'currency',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'level',
            type: 'numeric',
            format: '0.0000'
        },
        {
            data: 'units',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'asOf',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        },
        {
            data: 'onedChng',
            type: 'numeric',
            format: '0.00%'
        }
    ],
    stretchH: 'all',
    width: 806,
    autoWrapRow: true,
    height: 441,
    maxRows: 22,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: [
        'ID',
        'Country',
        'Code',
        'Currency',
        'Level',
        'Units',
        'Date',
        'Change'
    ]
};

  var hot1 = new Handsontable(hotElement1, hotSettings);
  var hot2 = new Handsontable(hotElement2, hotSettings);
```

```html
<div id="hot1"></div>
    <div id="hot2"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/pro/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://handsontable.com/static/css/main.css">
<script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/pro/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
```

Fiddle link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/0bx0exeo/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same data source for both the tables. Whenever you add new rows to one data source same reflects in the other one. Use two different data source and thus two different hotsettings like this and it will work fine.

```
 var dataObject = [
    {id: 1, flag: 'EUR', currencyCode: 'EUR', currency: 'Euro', level: 0.9033, units: 'EUR / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.0026},
    {id: 2, flag: 'JPY', currencyCode: 'JPY', currency: 'Japanese Yen', level: 124.3870, units: 'JPY / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.0001},
    {id: 3, flag: 'GBP', currencyCode: 'GBP', currency: 'Pound Sterling', level: 0.6396, units: 'GBP / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.00}
  ];
   var dataObject1 = [
    {id: 1, flag: 'EUR', currencyCode: 'EUR', currency: 'Euro', level: 0.9033, units: 'EUR / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.0026},
    {id: 2, flag: 'JPY', currencyCode: 'JPY', currency: 'Japanese Yen', level: 124.3870, units: 'JPY / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.0001},
    {id: 3, flag: 'GBP', currencyCode: 'GBP', currency: 'Pound Sterling', level: 0.6396, units: 'GBP / USD', asOf: '08/19/2015', onedChng: 0.00}
  ];

  var currencyCodes = ['EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'CAD', 'AUD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'BRL', 'CNY', 'RUB', 'INR', 'TRY', 'THB', 'IDR', 'MYR', 'MXN', 'ARS', 'DKK', 'ILS', 'PHP'];

  var flagRenderer = function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    var currencyCode = value;

    while (td.firstChild) {
      td.removeChild(td.firstChild);
    }

    if (currencyCodes.indexOf(currencyCode) > -1) {
      var flagElement = document.createElement('DIV');
      flagElement.className = 'flag ' + currencyCode.toLowerCase();
      td.appendChild(flagElement);

    } else {
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(value === null ? '' : value);
      td.appendChild(textNode);
    }
  };

  var hotElement1 = document.querySelector('#hot1');
  var hotElement2 = document.querySelector('#hot2');
  var hotElementContainer1 = hotElement1.parentNode;
  var hotElementContainer2 = hotElement2.parentNode;
  var hotSettings = {
    data: dataObject,
    contextMenu:  ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row', 'make_read_only'],
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'id',
            type: 'numeric',
            width: 40
        },
        {
            data: 'flag',
            renderer: flagRenderer
        },
        {
            data: 'currencyCode',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'currency',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'level',
            type: 'numeric',
            format: '0.0000'
        },
        {
            data: 'units',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'asOf',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        },
        {
            data: 'onedChng',
            type: 'numeric',
            format: '0.00%'
        }
    ],
    stretchH: 'all',
    width: 806,
    autoWrapRow: true,
    height: 441,
    maxRows: 22,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: [
        'ID',
        'Country',
        'Code',
        'Currency',
        'Level',
        'Units',
        'Date',
        'Change'
    ]
};

var hotSettings1 = {
    data: dataObject1,
    contextMenu:  ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row', 'make_read_only'],
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'id',
            type: 'numeric',
            width: 40
        },
        {
            data: 'flag',
            renderer: flagRenderer
        },
        {
            data: 'currencyCode',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'currency',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'level',
            type: 'numeric',
            format: '0.0000'
        },
        {
            data: 'units',
            type: 'text'
        },
        {
            data: 'asOf',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        },
        {
            data: 'onedChng',
            type: 'numeric',
            format: '0.00%'
        }
    ],
    stretchH: 'all',
    width: 806,
    autoWrapRow: true,
    height: 441,
    maxRows: 22,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: [
        'ID',
        'Country',
        'Code',
        'Currency',
        'Level',
        'Units',
        'Date',
        'Change'
    ]
};

  var hot1 = new Handsontable(hotElement1, hotSettings);
  var hot2 = new Handsontable(hotElement2, hotSettings1);
```

Working Fiddle of the same- http://jsfiddle.net/sanchitpatiyal95/0bx0exeo/5/